# validation of a Zero Adjusted Gamma model

Tags: model-selection, regression-strategies

I am using a Zero Adjusted Gamma regression (two-part ZAGA) model to estimate the effect of a psychometric categorical factor ("expected recovery", with 3 levels) on cost associated with treatment after whiplash injury. I have about 15 covariates/degrees of freedom that are relevant to the cost outcome and potential confounders. The ZAGA two-part model fits a logistic regression for the probability of having zero cost, and a gamma model (using log link) for those with cost outcome > 0. I understand that there are limitations with this type of models for the objective of interest, but for various reasons we need to stick with it for now.

For the logistic part, we have only 19 observations with zero cost, so we cannot use many covariates. It also unclear how the measured covariates are associated with the probability of having zero costs (i.e. deciding not to pursue any further treatment options). So we ended up using a "two-step" stepwise regression approach, including in the logistic model only the two covariates that had significant univariate association with I(cost=0).

On the other hand, we were able to include all covariates in the gamma model (we have more than 300 non zero cost observations). No two covariates had correlation > 0.8 so we decided to keep them all in the model. We would like to properly validate our model, keeping in mind that the main objective is the effect of (potentially modifiable) factor of perception of "expected recovery" and 1-yr health care cost (vs. prediction).

It is unclear to me, i) whether we could have done a better job in the model selection process, ii) what would be the appropriate ways to validate such two-part model and potentially apply shrinkage to tackle possible over-fitting.
Any ideas/suggestions/comments would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Nicholas

Comment: Its quite possible to have severe multicollinearity problems yet have no pairwise correlation above 0.8. I'm not criticizing your decision there, but you should be prepared for the possibility.

Comment: In fact I just made an example where the biggest pairwise correlation was 0.38 yet there was perfect multicollinearity (among 11 predictors of length 100); much smaller values would be simple to achieve.